# Value of a cell in the same row as the max value in another

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to add some stats to a google spreadsheet in which I am calculating the value of different purchases. I want to display the best and worst values with their title. I am trying this currently

```
=OFFSET(ADDRESS(MATCH(MAX(G2:G31),G2:G31,0),7), 0, -5) & " : " & MAX(G2:G31)
```

to try and get the output "Title : value"
but am getting Error: `Argument must be a range`. what am I missing?

Comment: What is the content of your cells?

Comment: the cells in row g are numbers and the ones in the offset row are strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADDRESS will return a string representation of a cell reference, rather than the reference itself. So you would need to wrap the ADDRESS function in INDIRECT.

However, the "title" will be wrong by one, as you are MATCHing in an array that starts at row 2 rather than row 1.

Using similar logic to your formula, perhaps something like:

`=OFFSET(B2,MATCH(MAX(G2:G31),G2:G31,0)-1,0)&" : "&MAX(G2:G31)`

or this will return multiple matches if there is more than one value equal to the maximum:

`=FILTER(B2:B31&" : "&G2:G31,G2:G31=MAX(G2:G31))`